# VB.NET Remove lines from the list containing bad words modified in another list?

Tags: vb.net, list

I am looking for ideas, how to remove lines from selected list containing bad words from another custom list? Here is small example:

List:

```
<Index item="25" name="Colligan">
<Index item="26" name="Michael">
<Index item="229" name="Julie">
<Index item="288" name="Robby">
<Index item="200" name="Andrea">
<Index item="299" name="Tommy">
```

Custom list with bad words:

- Colligan
- Julie
- Andrea
- Tommy

So after running cleaning process, I am getting cleaned list like this:

```
<Index item="26" name="Michael">
<Index item="288" name="Robby">
```

I found how to do small app deleting one or two custom bad words, but the thing is, that sometimes I will have more than 1000 bad words. Looking forward for every solution.

I found this code useful with one bad word, but not list of them:

```
Dim lines() As String
        Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)
        Dim searchString As String = "3"
        lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\test.txt")
        For Each line As String In lines
            If line.Contains(searchString) = False Then
                outputlines.Add(line)
            End If
        Next

        IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Temp\test.txt", outputlines)
```

I am beginner in programming, so don`t be angry for my question. Thanks

Comment: Which part of this task are you having trouble with exactly?  Your question doesn't make clear what it was about the solutions that you've already that tried were insufficient.

Comment: I am having trouble reading second list, checking every bad word in first list, then deleting line containing that bad word. In my example Lines containing colligan julie andrea and tommy were removed.

Comment: Having 2 or having 1000 "bad" words is not an issue per se. The logic should handle it regardless of the amount of data it has to depure. Are you having problems with performance (reading the complete second list every time to find the word)? Are you checking each token against the complete list of bad words? seems like a grouping problem where you have to find all the elements that belong to the first list and to the complement of the intersection of both lists. Please share with us what have you tried so far.

Comment: So it is an asp project? or normal window application? if so, it would be interesting to see your declaration of the variable which contains those things

Comment: That`s normal window app. I have updated my question with code for one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code, in principle, should work.  The only problem with it, though, is that it only looks for a single bad word.  You could change it to search for all the words by using a nested loop, like this:

```
Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)()
Dim badWords() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\badwords.txt")
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\test.txt")
    Dim badWordFound As Boolean = False
    For Each badWord As String in badWords
        If line.Contains(badWord) Then
            badWordFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not badWordFound Then
        outputlines.Add(line)
    End If
Next
File.WriteAllLines("C:\Temp\test.txt", outputlines)
```

Comment: Thanks Steve The thing is that, I was thinking of list with bad words. For example it can contains 1000 bad words. That`s will take me ages to write them down in Dim badWords() As String = {"Colligan", "Julie", "Andrea", "Tommy"} What I am looking, is pull automatically every line from bad word list and find them in new list, if found, remove ALL line containing current bad word.

Comment: Right, I just wrote it that way as a matter of example.  I would recommend loading them from a file into the array.  How to do that, though, will depend on the file format, which you, as of yet, have not provided.

Comment: Sorry, forgot  to mention the file format. File format would be simple txt file :)

Comment: @Chelovek: Should have no problem with that. Have one word per line in that file. Human readable and easy to edit.

Comment: If the text file were formatted as @Neolisk described, then you could simply say `badWords = File.ReadAllLines(...)`.

Comment: Thanks Steven, this last worked for me very well. Thank you :)